# How to handle exception that has been thrown from DoWork handler of BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, exception, backgroundworker

I want to handle exceptions that happen inside of `DoWork` handler in my `RunWorkerCompleted` handler but while code is running under debugger I'm getting another exception first "Exeption was unhandled by user code".

Here short example of code I'm using:

```cpp
BackgroundWorker _worker;
public void Test()
{
    _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
    _worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;

    _worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new
        RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = ActuallWorkHere();
}

private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = e.Error;
}

private IEnumerable<string> ActuallWorkHere()
{
    throw new Exception("test");
    // "Exeption was unhandled by user code" if called
    string[] res = { "test" };
    return res;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where exactly do you get the exception? I don't see a single try catch in your code!

Comment: "exeptiong first" should read "first chance exception".  That's normal, the exception is caught by the code that calls DoWork.  What you are supposed to do with it in RunWorkerCompleted is up to you.  You could write `if (e.Error != null) throw e.Error;` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not really doing anything wrong, this is what Visual Studio does with unhandled errors when running code in the debugger:

From [BackgroundWorker.DoWork Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) on MSDN:

> If you are running under the Visual Studio debugger, the debugger will
>   break at the point in the DoWork event handler where the unhandled
>   exception was raised.

Try running your compiled program and you won't see this.

Note that you can handle this exception in your DoWork and the [RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.error.aspx) property in your RunWorkerCompleted handler will still store details of your error.